# Fetching GROUP_CONCAT comma separated values using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

This is my query to iterate module_id. 
Ex: 1,2,3,4,5   (Using GROUP CONCAT).

```
 String sql="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(module_id) AS module_id
             FROM sox_customer_partner_modules "
          + "WHERE customer_id= :customer_id
             AND partner_id= :partner_id
             AND STATUS='1'";
```

My query is executing fine and it's returning result as 1,2,3,4,5. But when I'm iterating in java , it fetch only the first value i.e, 1

Using hibernate I'm fetching the records.

Problem is I can able to fetch only first record. Ex: 1

But I want to fetch like 1,2,3,4,5 as a String.

My java code is :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addScalar("module_id", Hibernate.INTEGER);
query.setParameter("customer_id", customer_id);
query.setParameter("partner_id", partner_id);

Integer module_id=0;
List<Object> CustModList = query.list();

return CustModList.toString(); //Which returns 1.. But I want 1,2,3,4,5
```

Please help needed . Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you miss the group by statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use GROUP BY, because traditionally, [MySQL has been the only RDBMS allowing optional GROUP BY predicates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Use this query:

```
String sql="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(module_id) AS module_id
         FROM sox_customer_partner_modules "
      + "WHERE customer_id= :customer_id
         AND partner_id= :partner_id
         AND STATUS='1' 
         GROUP BY customer_id, partner_id";
```

Of course you should know better which columns should identify a group.

Also change this line:

```
query.addScalar("module_id", Hibernate.INTEGER);
```

to:

```
query.addScalar("module_id", Hibernate.STRING);
```

Comment: The same answer . Problem in iterating in java itseems??.